# Which parts of an SVG created by Adobe Illustrator are safe to delete?

Tags: html, svg

As you see, most of this code of svg is create form ai. I think that may be some of code are unuseful and should delete?

```
<svg height="80" width="80" version="1.1" id="icon-user" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;" xml:space="preserve" fill="#434343">
        <path id="XMLID_1_" class="st0" d="M24,24H0c0,0,1.3-5.3,7.2-7.3C8.6,17.5,10.2,18,12,18s3.4-0.5,4.8-1.3C22.7,18.7,24,24,24,24z
           M20,8c0,4.4-3.6,8-8,8s-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8,8-8S20,3.6,20,8z M17.2,11H6.8c1,1.8,3,3,5.2,3S16.2,12.8,17.2,11z"/>
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator adds lots of things that are not necessary.

In your example you can delete:

**Group 1**

- `x="0px" y="0px"` These are meaningless at the root level
- `style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;"` Not needed because you aren't using filters. `enable-background` isn't reliably supported anyway.
- `xml:space="preserve"`. Because you aren't using any text elements
- `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. Because you are not using any `xlink` attributes.

**Group 2**

If you are not styling the SVG with CSS, or manipulating it with JS, you can also remove:

- `id="icon-user"`
- `id="XMLID_1_"`
- `class="st0"`

**Group 3**

If you are embedding this SVG inline in your HTML code. For example:

```
<div>
   <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

then you can also remove:

- `version="1.1"`
- `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

That means the minimal content that you need for an inlined SVG is:

```html
<svg height="80" width="80" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#434343">
  <path d="M24,24H0c0,0,1.3-5.3,7.2-7.3C8.6,17.5,10.2,18,12,18s3.4-0.5,4.8-1.3C22.7,18.7,24,24,24,24z
           M20,8c0,4.4-3.6,8-8,8s-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8,8-8S20,3.6,20,8z M17.2,11H6.8c1,1.8,3,3,5.2,3S16.2,12.8,17.2,11z"/>
</svg>
```

**External SVG**

If you are using the SVG as an external file. For example, you are linking to it with an `<img>`, `background-image`, `<object>` or `<embed>`, then you can safely remove the items listed in group 1 and group 2.  But don't remove the things in group 3.

```
<svg height="80" width="80" version="1.1" id="icon-user" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#434343">
        <path id="XMLID_1_" class="st0" d="M24,24H0c0,0,1.3-5.3,7.2-7.3C8.6,17.5,10.2,18,12,18s3.4-0.5,4.8-1.3C22.7,18.7,24,24,24,24z
           M20,8c0,4.4-3.6,8-8,8s-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8,8-8S20,3.6,20,8z M17.2,11H6.8c1,1.8,3,3,5.2,3S16.2,12.8,17.2,11z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much , really help.